# Is there a way to incrementally process format specifier strings in C?

Tags: c, stream, stdio, standard-library, format-specifiers

In embedded programming, I often end up with code that looks something like this:

```
void debug_terminal_printf(const char* format, va_list ap){
    char tmp[ARBITRARY_LIMITATION];
    vsprintf( tmp, format, ap );
    for(int pos=0; pos<strlen(tmp); pos++){
        if( tmp[pos] == 0 ) break;
        uart_putc( tmp[pos] );
    }
}
```

I want my interface to provide the convenience of string formats, but typically the consumers of the formatted string are things that consume the formatted strings a few bytes at a time, like a UART in this case. So I end up with these little temporary buffers in each of my helper functions. Use of dynamic memory is not really suitable, because decisions about the use of dynamic memory are made at the system level, and it would be inappropriate to use it in embedded platform code.

What I *wish* to be able to do is process the string incrementally, something like this:

```
void debug_terminal_printf(const char* format, va_list ap){
    char tmp[MAX_TOKEN_SIZE];
    while(*format){
        int len = single_token_sprintf( tmp, format, ap );
        uart_puts(tmp);
        format += len;
    }
}
```

This way I never need enough memory for the entire formatted string, I can wait until that hardware has consumed the last token before continuing to decode the next token.

Has anyone ever seen a (hopefully portable) idiom like this that gets rid of the need for a large temporary buffer?

Comment: I deleted that comment after noticing your remark about run time. But are you so tight on stack memory that you cannot use a local buffer?

Comment: Often serial access can be handled through `fopen()` even in embedded,  Is `fprintf()` an option?

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do this portably. You need some way to hook into the output buffering of `stdio` streams.

Comment: @weather-van. Right now, using the stack is exactly what I am doing. However this is a very rude thing to do, because one person might want to use something "debug print" to print tiny strings from a context with tens of bytes of stack, and someone else might want to print a massive 1KB string from another context where stack isn't an issue. In my environment, variable stack translate to a literal call to malloc(), so that isn't an option. I could make the caller provide the neccessary scratch space explicitly, however at some point my function changes from a "helper" to a "hinder".

Comment: Could process the `format` looking for `"%"`.  If the types used is a small-ish sub-set like `%d` `%s`, then code could handle the debug print one argument at a time with  a `switch(format_specifier)`

Comment: @Chux - I think you might have found the answer I am looking for fprintf and (retarget.c) ! Can you post a short answer that I can approve?

Comment: Which comment?? I posted 2

Comment: @chux - It looks like I need to read up on this: http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/gsac/gsac_retargetcortex.htm

Comment: If it is about my first comment, looks like you could post own based on your referenced link.

Answer (score 0):

Big thanks to @chux for guiding me in the right direction.

The answer is that the runtime environment's implementation of putc() can be hooked so that when fprintf is called, I can consume the resulting strings one byte at a time. The is quite non-portable. For each environment the exact way to accomplish this will be different.

In my case (Cortex M on Keil), the instructions are provided by Keil here:
http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/gsac/gsac_retargetcortex.htm